# k8s apply yaml files does not get same result from command lines

Tags: kubernetes

I have a spring boot application. I want to load to my k8s (master + kubectl, 172.16.100.83) Our image registry is at 192.168.1.229:5000.

```
1) With command window
a. docker pull 192.168.1.229:5000/gearboxrack/gearbox-rack-eureka-server
b. kubectl run gearbox-rack-eureka-server --image=192.168.1.229:5000/gearboxrack/gearbox-rack-eureka-server --port=8761 
c. kubectl expose deployment gearbox-rack-eureka-server --type NodePort
[root@master3 supwisdom]# kubectl get svc
NAME                         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
gearbox-rack-eureka-server   NodePort    10.103.109.185   <none>        8761:30719/TCP   6s
kubernetes                   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP          1h
```

Then I successfully launch the application by `172.16.100.83:30719`. Notice now port is generated randomly by k8s.

Now I use yaml file to try to get some result/goal.

eureka_pod.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: gearbox-rack-eureka-server
  labels:
    purpose: platform_eureka_demo
spec:
  containers:
  - name:  gearbox-rack-eureka-server
    image: 192.168.1.229:5000/gearboxrack/gearbox-rack-eureka-server
    ports:
        - containerPort: 8761
```

my eureka_svc.yaml files is

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: gearbox-rack-eureka-server
  labels:
    name: gearbox_rack_eureka_server
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 8761
      nodePort: 31501
      name: tcp


[root@master3 supwisdom]# kubectl apply -f eureka_pod.yaml
pod "gearbox-rack-eureka-server" created

[root@master3 supwisdom]# kubectl apply -f  eureka_svc.yaml
service "gearbox-rack-eureka-server" created
[root@master3 supwisdom]# kubectl get services
NAME                         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
gearbox-rack-eureka-server   NodePort    10.99.100.123   <none>        8761:31501/TCP   11s
kubernetes                   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1       <none>        443/TCP          2h
```

But now I try `172.16.100.83:31501`, I could not get same result as command lines did. Are there something wrong with my steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

usually services need a **selector** to find the pod. Also you might need to specify **targetPort** in the service spec.

I think this should work in your case.

Add this to the pod labels

```
labels:
  app: my-app
```

Add this to the service

```
spec:
  selector:
    app: my-app
```

Comment: What does targetPort mean? port 8761 is exposed by spring boot application. NodePort 31501 is the port I specifiy host port which will forward traffic to port 8761. Then what does target Port stand for?

Comment: Hi, the service is what actually exposes your container to other containers. targetPort is definitely needed when your pod listens on more than one ports, in this case you select which port of the pod to expose to which port on the service.